# Replace text inside a div without affecting any HTML tags inside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see that this has been asked many times. But, unfortunately I have not come across a straight forward solution. Most solutions revolve around multiple nodes within the div.

So here's problem. I have the following markup:

```
<div class="test">Text1<span></span></div>
```

I need "Text1" to be replaced with "Text2" without affecting the span tag and event handlers attached to the span tag.

Doing something like `$('.test')html('Text2<span></span>')` does replace the text. But, removes the event handlers on the span tag, which is not desired. I am looking for a quick and efficient method for this one.

Comment: How are you going to determine what text you want to replace?  Is the text always before the first tag?

Comment: And in response to what event?

Comment: Changing the markup (wrapping the text in an element) is by far the simplest fix for this.

Comment: @brad Yes the text will always precede the span tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap replaceable text with a tag:

```
<div class="test"><span class="test-text">Text1</span><span></span></div>
```

Comment: I guess this is by far the easiest solution. Though it never crossed my mind. Thx for the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can access the [Text Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textnode) itself with [contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/). Now if you know that the element starts with text you can do this:

```
$($('.test').contents()[0]).replaceWith('New Text')​;
```

Now if you didn't know the location in the array of the Text Node, you can filter with:

```
return this.nodeType === 3;
```

and compare the text values (if you know those).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eKfR9/)

Comment: Thx for the reply. I see that you have this working in Fiddle. But, unfortunately this throws an illegal character error at the end of the statement for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you would add event handler with `.live` or `.on` functions (depends on jQuery version) .html('Text2') would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

On the assumption that the text to be replaced will always precede the existing span, that it will always be the `firstChild` *and* that it will be an unwrapped textNode:

```
$('.test').click(
    function() {
        this.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Text2';
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j4sQB/).

To ensure that only the first textNode is changed, regardless of where it's found within the `.test` element:

```
$('.test').click(
    function(e) {
        var newText = 'Text2',
            children = e.target.childNodes;
        for (var i=0,len=children.length;i<len;i++){
            if (children[i].nodeName == '#text'){
                children[i].nodeValue = newText;
                return false;
            }
        }
    });​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j4sQB/1/).