# jQuery unintentionally deletes links

Tags: jquery, html

So I have the follow jQuery code:

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}   
var regex = new RegExp(getUrlParameter('suche'),"gi");
$('table td').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(regex,'<span class="yellow">$&</span>'));
});
```

It does what it has to do (marking up strings in a table that contain a given search string) but it also deletes all `<a href>` in that table. The table works like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Head</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some content including search strings</td>
        <td>
            <a href="profile.php?search=$search string&id=$id">Profile</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

At first I thought that it was because it includes the search string that gets replaced by the `<span>`, but it does not work even without it. If I right click > view source code, it does not even show that theres a link (it just looks like `<td>Profile</td>`). I have absolutely no clue where this comes from but it definitely has something to do with the jQuery because if I comment it out, the link works like intended.

Comment: Your href attribute is missing the closing double quotes:
`href="profile.php?search=$search string&id=$id"`

is that in your live code as well?

Comment: No,i just typed it up,everything is correct there.^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `text()`, which will include only "Profile" in your second `td`.

```
<td><a href="....">Profile</a></td>
```

You're doing a replacement on that string, then calling `html()` to use it as the *entire* contents of the `td`:

```
<td>Profile</td>
```

If you're *very* confident about your replacement text not conflicting with your HTML, you'll want to say:

```
$(this).html(
  $(this).html().replace(regex,'<span class="yellow">$&</span>')
);
```

to preserve your tags. But your safest bet is to replace only in text nodes. See, for example, [Replace text inside a div without affecting any HTML tags inside of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10078508/replace-text-inside-a-div-without-affecting-any-html-tags-inside-of-it?rq=1)

Comment: 'Profile' is a good example that will create an unwanted behavior, as the word 'profile' within the href attribute will also be replaced by the `<span>`. PO will need a more sophisticated solutions., maybe like the one you linked. If you know the structure exactly, it is easy.

Comment: Thank you very much.I now have a td class that i use for the jquery loop $('table td.class').each(function () {...} and it works like a charm.